# Выборка данных, циклы

Tags: php, mysqli

Возникла следующая задача: вывести количество игроков онлайн.
Есть такой код:

```
    $admins = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT PlayerName,Admin FROM `players` WHERE Admin > 0");
    $players = $samp->getBasicPlayers();
    foreach($players as $plrs) {
            $player .= $plrs["nickname"];
    }
    while($pAdmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admins)){
        if($player == $pAdmin["PlayerName"]){
            $plrr .= "[".$pAdmin["Admin"]."] ".$plrs["nickname"]."
";
        }
    }
```

Я пытаюсь выбрать всех админов из базы данных, затем с помощью внешней библиотеки получаю массив игроков с игрового сервера, которые сейчас онлайн.

**Первый цикл** выводит всех игроков в строку, так как другого решения я просто не могу придумать
**Второй цикл** как бы проверяет соответствие строки к массиву админов из базы данных. Конечно это не правильно, я понимаю, но даже перевод второго массива в строку не дает нужных результатов.

То есть я пытаюсь проверить, соответствует ли некнеймы игроков из базы к никнеймам игроков из сервера.

Буду рад любой помощи в поисках ошибки, так как в PHP я только осваиваюсь

Comment: а не зя вначале массивы создать $player[]; $pla[]=$pAdmin["PlayerName"]; а потом array_diff() применить

Comment: `array_intersect($arr1,$arr2)` вернёт всех игроков из массива $arr1, которые есть во втором массиве ($arr2), `array_diff($arr1,$arr2)` вернёт всех с массива $arr1, которых нет в массиве $arr2. Тут решение зависит от того, что вам нужно делать дальше.. можно привести оба массива к "одинаковому" виду и через `array_intersect()` вывести всех игроков которые существуют в базе и онлайн

Comment: Понятное дело, $players будет доступен только в массиве foreach))) Заметте что сначала выполняется foreach а потом while поэтому в $player у вас будет всего 1 значение(Последнее записанное в эту переменную.)

Comment: @makcim512 то есть всех игроков вытащить из цикла foreach не получится, как я понял. И циклы в циклах такое себе применение...

Comment: @InDevX скорее всего именно это мне и нужно, найти совпадения среди игроков в базе и онлайн. и `array_intersect()` думаю мне должен подойти, благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как то так))) Функция in_array() Сравнивает строку с элементами массива. Если есть совпвдение то in_array() = true если нет совпадений то false.

```
$admins = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT PlayerName,Admin FROM `players` WHERE Admin > 0");
$admin_array = array();
$user_array  = array();
$players = $samp->getBasicPlayers();

foreach($players as $plrs) {
   array_push($user_array ,$plrs["nickname"]);
}

while($pAdmin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admins)){
  if(in_array($pAdmin["Admin"] ,$user_array)){
     array_push($admin_array ,array("[".$pAdmin["Admin"]."] ".$plrs["nickname"]."");
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это очень помогло мне)